# Send a push notification trough https cloud function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

Assuming that I created the notification to the user on a separate function, how can I use a https Cloud Function to send a push notification to a user?
So far, I tried this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const payload = {
    token: request.query.token,
    notification: {
      title: request.query.title,
      body: request.query.body
    },
    data: {
      body: request.query.body
    }
  };

  admin.messaging().send(payload).then(response => {
    console.log('Done!');
  });
});
```

However, it doesn't appear to be working, and I have no idea why. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: How are you sending the token to the cloud function? Remember the token is the fcm token gotten from the client side sdk. If your client is a flutter app, there are other parameters to set in the data object.

Comment: I'm using an external function:
```export function sendNotificationToUser(title, body, user, token)```
and yes, I'm calling that function from the client side

Comment: Did you receive an error?

Comment: Not really, in fact, it was actually a network error. Alas, I'm posting my solution in a few hours. Thanks!